# NOT IN didn't work with the queryBuilder of Symfony 6.2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my project, I have an AJAX request allowing me to retrieve a JSON display of users to add as a friend.
The problem is that my query doesn't seem to work when I want to not retrieve users who are already friends. Here is the code of my query:

```
public function findBySearchFriend(Utilisateur $user, $value = null): array
   {
        $friends = $user->getAmis();

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->andWhere('u.pseudo LIKE :val')
           ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
           ->andWhere('u != :user')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
        //    ->andWhere('u NOT IN (:friends)')
        //    ->setParameter('friends', $friends)
           ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
           ->setMaxResults(10)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```

When both lines in the code are commented out, the query works. But it gets me back users already as a friend.

I have already tried several solutions without success. Am I required to use RAW SQL for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Typo? `->setParameter('amis', $fiends)` should be `->setParameter('friends', $friends)` to be able to reference the `:friends` param. Though it would make more sense to use an exclusion JOIN or subquery instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've translate it for the topic and forget this one. It's edit :) the problem didn't come from that

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/expression-builder.html#notin

Comment: I replaced my two lines with this:
->expr()->notIn('u', $friends)
But the code does not compile with orderBy() method

Comment: That was for `Collection::matching()` not the [QueryBuilder expressions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-d355222ea2bf3af2880c1a9199a32eeac3db714f-84).

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" - what does that mean? Are you facing any error message? If you dump the generated query, does it look as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I think NOT IN was not appropriate and tried with NOT MEMBER OF like this:

```
public function findBySearchFriend(Utilisateur $user, $value = null): array
   {
        $friends = $user->getAmis();

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->andWhere('u.pseudo LIKE :val')
           ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
           ->andWhere('u != :user')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
           ->andWhere(':user NOT MEMBER OF u.estAmisDe')
           ->setParameter('user', $user) 
           ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
           ->setMaxResults(10)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match an object instead of a field that's why it is throwing an error. Please use `u.id` or `u.friend` whatever is a relation to the User entity.

```
public function findBySearchFriend(Utilisateur $user, $value = null): array
   {
        $friends = $user->getAmis();

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->andWhere('u.pseudo LIKE :val')
           ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
           ->andWhere('u != :user')
           ->setParameter('user', $user)
           ->andWhere('u.id NOT IN (:friends)')
           ->setParameter('friends', $friends)
           ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
           ->setMaxResults(10)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
```